# Как компилятор получает коэффициенты для генерации псевдослучайных чисел?

Tags: c++, c#, visual-studio, криптография, случайные-числа

Здравствуйте. Задался вопросом генерации псевдослучайных чисел в Visual Studio 2013 на c++ и c#. В информации, найденной в Интернете, говорится, что многие компиляторы (вроде и Visual Studio?) используют линейный конгруэнтный метод. В этом методе используются коэффициенты ([ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4)).

И вот вопрос: как компилятор задает эти коэффициенты? На основе чего он их получает, откуда берет и т.д.? Как я понимаю, они не могут быть жестко заданы в компиляторе, а должны быть разные при каждом вызове рандома, иначе всегда будут получаться одинаковые последовательности.

Буду благодарен за информацию или ссылки.

Comment: http://www.random.org/

Comment: @Колямбий - если не использовать srand, то последовательности будут одинаковыми.

Comment: @Колямбий, говоря 

    как компилятор задает эти коэффициенты?

Вы хотите спросить -- **откуда программист, который писал функцию `rand()`, взял эти коэффициенты?**.

--

Дело тут в том, что **компилятор** никакого отношения к устройству `rand()` не имеет, и для него вызов `rand()` ничем не отличается от вызова других функций.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это "зашито" (реализовано) не в компиляторе, а в классах.  В С# есть класс `Random`, который генерирует псевдослучайные числа. И этот класс реализует метод, описанный Кнутом в этой [книге](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0201896842/codihorr-20). Как сам метод на русском будет, не знаю. При создании класса можно передать начальное значение (Seed), на основе которого будут генерироваться случайные числа. Если не передавать никакие параметры, то по умолчанию значение будет равно количеству тиков, которое прошло с момента запуска компьютера.

Также есть более продвинутый класс `RandomNumberGenerator` в пространстве имен  `System.Security.Cryptography`. Он уже использует больше параметров для генерации, кроме вышеупомянутого, применяется ID текущего процесса, потока, текущее время, хеш сумма различных параметров текущей среды (имя пользователя, имя компьютера и т.п.).